# Is it possible to use maven-bundle-plugin (bnd) to generate plugin.xml

Tags: java, maven, eclipse-plugin, osgi, bnd

I know that bnd in maven-bundle-plugin uses POM first approach to build Eclipse plugins.

This is what I would prefer rather than using Tycho and MANIFEST first approach. But my plugin needs also the `plugin.xml` file to define extension points.

Is there some possibility to use maven-bundle-plugin or bnd to generate this file also ?

Comment: What information would you want to generate that from? Is just providing a predefined `plugin.xml` not an option? Would the `plugin.xml` be subject to changes often?

Comment: @stempler There are some duplicated information in source code and plugin.xml, but from what I understand from Neil answer, I need to author it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, and possibly you should not use maven-bundle-plugin for Eclipse plugins development.

There has been historical disagreement between older OSGi creaters and Eclipse way, and up to now there's no tools that would help you to author both general OSGi (where bnd is the best and only), and Eclipse plugins, where there is still Manifest+plugin.xml first approach.

Comment: Thanks, I already abadon maven way for Eclipse plugin management and use the following approach - implement all possible logic in standard maven based and managed  java library and than only wrap it inside plugin.

Comment: Well, you can use maven/tycho as additional non-intrusive tool for Eclipse (e.g. only for command line or CI) by adding minimal pom.xml
But with your way you can create plugin not only for Eclipse, but other Java GUI as well.

Answer (score 1):

`plugin.xml` is not a file that can be generated; you need to author it like a source file. If you do this then you can definitely use bnd and/or maven-bundle-plugin to include it into your bundle.